# Unable to save images as .png on PyCharm

Tags: python

I am trying to save this plot as a .png file on my computer, but when I run the code it does not save it (documentation available [here](https://stackoverflow.com)). I don't get any error message, it just does not get saved as a .png file.

```
sim.analysis.plotSpikeHist(include=['population1'])
simConfig.analysis['plotSpikeHist'] = {'saveFig': 'SpikeHist.png'}
```

This however works (having imported `matplotlib.pyplot as plt`):

```
sim.analysis.plotSpikeHist(include=['population1'])
plt.savefig ('SpikeHist.png')
```

Any idea as to why?

Comment: Looks like you accidentally linked Stack Overflow instead of the documentation. You can [edit] to fix it.

Comment: BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour] and [ask] for tips.

Comment: I'm not familiar with this library, whatever it is, but FWIW, I don't imagine setting a config key (`'plotSpikeHist'`) would cause the image to be saved. Maybe you need to do that before running the `.plotSpikeHist(...)`? Maybe you even need to run `plt.savefig()` after?